# Data not maintaining on editing an unlocked cell in proteced sheet

Tags: excel

I have a problem with editing a unlocked cell in a protected sheet.

When i double click on an unlocked cell in proctected sheet the data in the particular cell dissapears.if i have a text about 200 characters and like to edit it by double clicking the particular cell the whole data dissapears then the i have type the whole data with corrections.Please help.i even tried hidden = false for the particular cell but i found no luck.Please help.

My code:

```
ActiveSheetUnprotect "excel"
ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
ActiveSheet.Range("a1:br42").Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Range("e1:e37").Locked = False
ActiveSheet.Range("e1:e37").Hidden = False
ActiveSheet.Range("a1:br42").FormulaHidden = True
ActiveSheet.Protect "excel"
```

Comment: This sounds very odd! Can you share the file?

Comment: Are there any events (esp `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`) that might mess with the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `FormulaHidden` to `False` for the cells in question:

`ActiveSheet.Range("a1:br42").FormulaHidden = False`

Comment: Super,unbelievable,pentastic,mindblowing barrowc.U r amazing.Thanks Man.Thank you very much.